# Sentry error upon launch of react-native app

Tags: xcode, react-native, sentry

I'm trying to launch a react-native app in Xcode, the build succeeds but errors on the launch page.

The error I get is:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*****/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sentry.framework/Sentry
>     Reason: image not found

Here are the relevant dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"react-native": "^0.43.3",
"react-native-sentry": "^0.6.0",
```

Comment: Hey, please consider using the latest version of react-native-sentry. We've many bugs and removed Swift so this should no longer happen.

Comment: Hi. So I have updated sentry and am now able to build the app but am not able to use debugger tools. I get error:

/Users/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*****/Build/Intermediates/***.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/****.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh: line 6: ../node_modules/react-native-sentry/bin/bundle-frameworks: No such file or directory
Skipping bundling for Simulator platform
Continuing in background.
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Comment: Please check the docs, the build steps have been changed drastically. https://docs.sentry.io/clients/react-native/
There is no bundle-frameworks step anymore.